# Scroll down html element (<ul>) that is just visibility:none

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've got a dropdown menu in a framework. The dropdown menu part is simply hidden. On hover of the parent element the visibility is set to display.

I can easily add in a fadeIn / fadeOut effect due to the positioning of the dropdown menu as it is on the visible part of the page, but just hidden.

What i want to do is on hover of the parent element, instead of it just being shown, i want it to slide down.

What is the best approach to doing this? Set the  dropdown to be 0 height, and then animate it's height to give a slide effect? Is there a css3 animation that will do this better than js?

I can't really modify the html for the menu or the base css that positions it initially as it's quite complicated. But wondered if it was possible to do something like i'm suggesting?

Comment: by `scroll effect`, do you mean `slide`?

Comment: unfortunately it's not possible to achieve a css transition of a property from `0` to `auto`. If you have 5 list-items each one `1em` tall, you could animate the height from `0` to `5em`

Comment: Yes sorry, i do mean slide!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `display: none` instead of `visible: hidden`.

For sliding effect you can use `slideDown` and `slideUp` methods

```
$ul = $('#parentElement ul');
$('#parentElement').hover(
    function() {
        $ul.stop().slideDown("fast");
    },
    function() {
        $ul.stop().slideUp("fast");
    }
);
```

[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/FjWSu/)